# Acer Aspire Laptop won't charge in Windows 7 Home Premium x64

Tags: windows-7, charging, acpi, battery, ac-adapter

I have an Acer Aspire 7750-6801 laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit OS.  The issue is that it will only charge sometimes when plugged in.  I thought it might be a hardware issue, so I tried charging with the laptop off, and it works fine.  Also when in Linux, or any other environment other than Windows, it also charges fine.  The intermittent charging issue ONLY presents itself when in Windows.

I've tried the following:

```
Open Device Manager
Under 'Batteries->', I uninstalled 'Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery'
Then re-installed using 'Scan for hardware changes'
```

Still no luck.  It's quite urgent, any help would be appreciated as I am totally at a loss...

Comment: Have you checked the battery limits? Sometimes, OSes set it so batteries only will charge if the have less than x% remaining (commonly 85%)

Comment: Yes, even when it is as low as 3% it isn't charging, yet at other times, even when it is at 75% it will charge for a bit then stop.  I thought it was hardware because of this, but testing it in different environments shows it works fine.  Definitely appears to be an OS issue, but I'm not incredibly familiar with the Windows7 ACPI environment, so I was hoping someone could give me insight into it a bit more...